# D3 Pack Layout symmetry got changed in version greater than v4.5

Tags: d3.js

I was using d3 version 4.5 earlier in my project for d3 pack circles. Now I have used latest version and got difference in pack layout symmetry. [Before Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX2Zq.png) and [After Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwLjW.png)

Here is my code in both cases. Want to have same symmetry as it was in earlier version. Is there any new way to get this symmetry in latest version of d3.

```js
var diameter = 250;
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var bubble = d3.pack(data)
  .size([diameter, 185])
  .padding(1.4);

var svg = d3.select("#trending-topic")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", diameter)
  .attr("height", 185)
  .attr("class", "bubble");

var nodes = d3.hierarchy(data)
  .sum(function(d) {
    return d.Count;
  });

var format = d3.format(",d");
d3.selection.prototype.moveToFront = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
  });
};

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(bubble(nodes)
    .descendants())
  .enter()
  .filter(function(d) {
    return !d.children;
  })
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  })
  .attr("title", function(d) {
    return d.Name;
  });

/* transparent circle with border */
node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d.r;
    //return d.data.Radius;
  })
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return d.data.fillColor;
  })
  .on("click", function(d) {
    getTopicArticle(d.data.tid);
  });

node.append("text")
  .each(function(d) {
    var arr = d.data.Name.split(" ");

    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(arr[i].length > 10) {
        arr[i] = arr[i].substring(0, 7) + '...';
      }
      d3.select(this)
        .append("tspan")
        .text(arr[i])
        .attr("dy", i ? "1.2em" : 0)
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("class", "tspan" + i)
        .attr("fill", "white")
        .attr("font-size", function(d) {
          return d.r / 3;

        })
        .on("click", function(d) {
          getTopicArticle(d.data.tid);
        });
    }
    d3.select(this)
      .append("title")
      .text(d.data.Name);
  });
d3.select(self.frameElement)
  .style("height", 185 + "px");
d3.selectAll(".node")
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {

    var circle = d3.select(this)
      .select("circle");

    var text = d3.select(this)
      .selectAll("tspan");
    text.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .attr("font-size", function(d) {
        return d.r;
      });


  })
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {

  })
  .on("mouseleave", function(d) {

    var circle = d3.select(this)
      .select("circle");

    circle.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return d.r;
      });
    var text = d3.select(this)
      .selectAll("tspan");
    text.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .attr("font-size", function(d) {
        return d.r / 3;
      });
  });
```

Comment: Can you share your data? Right now it's guess work without it

Answer (score 1):

You were right, it's [this commit](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/commit/f5cbbb3a4ce31b7085bafc56a2d555187f632ee1) in `d3-hierarchy` between `1.1.1` and `1.1.2`, which in turn was introduced between d3 `4.5.0` and `4.5.1`. It addresses [this issue](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/issues/78), about packing circles more condensely.

I recommend just accepting the changes, but if you really don't want to change the layout, import `d3-hierarchy 1.1.1 *after*` d3` to override the hierarchy module. This returns the same layout as the older version of d3:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-hierarchy/1.1.1/d3-hierarchy.min.js"></script>
```

The downside is that by making the package versions out of sync, you might break something now or in the future, so it's not a long term sustainable approach.

---

**To test** use the following snippet and comment/uncomment the script imports.

```js
var diameter = 250;
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var data = {
  children: [{
      Name: 'Economy',
      fillColor: 'grey',
      Count: 12
    },
    {
      Name: 'Politics',
      fillColor: 'grey',
      Count: 10
    },
    {
      Name: 'ESG',
      fillColor: 'lightblue',
      Count: 5
    },
    {
      Name: 'Tech',
      fillColor: 'lightblue',
      Count: 5
    },
    {
      Name: 'Leisure',
      fillColor: 'pink',
      Count: 4
    },
    {
      Name: 'Coronavirus',
      fillColor: 'pink',
      Count: 4
    },
    {
      Name: 'Blockchain',
      fillColor: 'darkblue',
      Count: 2,
    },
    {
      Name: 'Sports',
      fillColor: 'darkblue',
      Count: 2,
    },
    {
      Name: 'Coding',
      fillColor: 'purple',
      Count: 1,
    },
    {
      Name: 'India',
      fillColor: 'purple',
      Count: 1,
    }
  ],
};

var bubble = d3.pack(data).size([diameter, 185]).padding(1.4);

var svg = d3.select("#trending-topic")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", diameter)
  .attr("height", 185)
  .attr("class", "bubble");

var nodes = d3.hierarchy(data)
  .sum(function(d) {
    return d.Count;
  });

var format = d3.format(",d");
d3.selection.prototype.moveToFront = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
  });
};

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(bubble(nodes).descendants())
  .enter()
  .filter(function(d) {
    return !d.children
  })
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  })
  .attr("title", function(d) {
    return d.Name;
  });

/* transparent circle with border */
node.append("circle").attr("r", function(d) {
  return d.r;
  //return d.data.Radius;
}).style("fill", function(d, i) {
  return d.data.fillColor;
});

node.append("text").each(function(d) {
  var arr = d.data.Name.split(" ");

  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].length > 10) {
      arr[i] = arr[i].substring(0, 7) + '...';
    }
    d3.select(this).append("tspan")
      .text(arr[i])
      .attr("dy", i ? "1.2em" : 0)
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("class", "tspan" + i).attr("fill", "white").attr("font-size", function(d) {
        return d.r / 3;
      });
  }
  d3.select(this).append("title").text(d.data.Name);
});
d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", 185 + "px");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.1/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-hierarchy/1.1.1/d3-hierarchy.min.js"></script>
<div id="trending-topic"></div>
```